# How does namespace works during function call in python?

Tags: python, function, namespaces

It is described in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#def) that -

A function definition is an executable statement. Its execution binds the function name in the current local namespace to a function object (a wrapper around the executable code for the function). This function object contains a reference to the current global namespace as the global namespace to be used when the function is called.

```
def func1():
    def func2():
        print("HELLO")    
func1()
func2()

NameError: name 'func2' is not defined
```

After execution of func1, the definition of func2 gets executed and its function object is referenced to the global namespace. Now even after the presence of function object of func2 in global namespace why I'm not able to call func2 from outside the body of func1.

I'm new to programming and I'm doing this just to have a good grasp on functions, if I'm having any misconsuption please explain how does namespace works during a function call.

Comment: "This function object contains a reference to the current global namespace" does not mean "the function's name is added to the current global namespace". I think you're interpreting things backwards. `func2` can access global values, but the global namespace can't access `func2`.

Comment: Thank you I've got your point. 
Suppose we are having a function call to func1 from inside the body of func2, it is completely valid, but how is this possible when we don't have a func1 name in the local namespace of func2 since func1 is binded in local namespace of func1 during execution of definition.

Comment: `func1` isn't bound in the local namespace of `func1`. It's bound in the global namespace. Since `func2` can access the global namespace, it can access `func1`.

Comment: Does the bounding of func2 happen in local namespace of func2?

Comment: `func2` exists in the local namespace of `func1` only.